# What is the cr or lf char in text taken from a webpage text area?

Tags: html, sql-server

I am saving copy from a textarea on a web page into a sql server db. This process preserves the carriage return and line feed when displaying the text elsewhere.

I want to add some content to the same field programmatic-ally - does anyone know what the characters are that create this cr and lf? I cannot determine them using ASCII converters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CR + LF is as follows in T-SQL:

```
SELECT 'foo' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'bar';
```

In a lot of cases it is important to include both and it is important to list them in that specific order.

Answer (score 0):

When HTML is displayed it will mostly ignore white-space, so a CR+LF in the HTML (carriage return and line-feed) will not cause a new line to be shown in the HTML rendered in a browser.

Instead, HTML uses [paragraph tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp) `<p></p>`, and [line-break tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) `<br />` for paragraphs and line-breaks respectively.